# Set of first words in sql

Tags: mysql

I have table accounts where I store accounts with name and other data. Name of account always begins with predefined word like alfa, omega and others that are not known yet. That list will be expanded. How can I get all accounts which starts with names but using only one LIKE, not one Like per every name?

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name LIKE 'alfa%' AND name LIKE 'omega%'.
```

But I want to similar to

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name LIKE '(alfa|omega)%';
```

Comment: select * from accounts where name like '% alfa% omega%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RLIKE`

```
SELECT name FROM accounts WHERE name RLIKE '^(alfa|omega)';
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of SQL are you using? If you're using MySQL you can use:

```
    WHERE name REGEXP 'alpha|omega'
```